# php - prepend an array value with key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array. It looks like this

```
$choices = array(
array('label' => 'test1','value' => 'test1'),
array('label' => 'test2','value' => 'test2'),
array('label' => 'test3','value' => 'test3'),
)
```

Now i would like to prepend this value in `$choices` array

```
array('label' => 'All','value' => 'all'),
```

It looks like I cannot use `array_unshift` function since my array has keys.

Can someone tell me how to prepend?

Comment: yes, it'll work just fine. even though you don't have explicitly defined keys in $choices, every **HAS** to have keys.

Comment: I don't see why you can't use `array_unshift`; every array has keys.

Comment: It looks like you can. The outer array is a list, with numeric keys. What you put inside (a distinct associative array) doesn't matter.

Comment: copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371016/php-prepend-associative-array-with-literal-keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$choices` array has only numeric keys so `array_unshift()` would do exactly what you want.

```
$choices = array(
    array('label' => 'test1','value' => 'test1'),
    array('label' => 'test2','value' => 'test2'),
    array('label' => 'test3','value' => 'test3'),
);
echo $choices[0]['label']; // echoes 'test1'

$array_to_add = array('label' => 'All','value' => 'all');
array_unshift($choices, $array_to_add);

/* resulting array would look like this:
$choices = array(
    array('label' => 'All','value' => 'all')
    array('label' => 'test1','value' => 'test1'),
    array('label' => 'test2','value' => 'test2'),
    array('label' => 'test3','value' => 'test3'),
);
*/
echo $choices[0]['label']; // echoes 'All'
```

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. I'll accept your answer after 7 minutes