# Change position of elements in an associative array in php

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an associative array as :

```
$headers=
Array
(
    [MODULE_ID] => Module ID
    [PLATFORM_ID] => Platform ID
    [PACKAGE_GUID] => Package GUID
    [AGGREGATE_PACKAGE] => Aggregate Package
    [DELD] => Deld
)
```

Now I wish to change the position ofPackage ID at the top  to resemble as :

```
 $desired=
Array
(
    [PACKAGE_GUID] => Package GUID
    [MODULE_ID] => Module ID
    [PLATFORM_ID] => Platform ID
    [AGGREGATE_PACKAGE] => Aggregate Package
    [DELD] => Deld
)
```

I tried `array_unshift` method but it does not works in this case as it is an associative array.

```
unset($headers['PACKAGE_GUID']);
array_unshift($headers, 'PACKAGE_GUID');
```

How can I achieve it?
Thanks.

Comment: `I tried array_unshift`<- Show us your attempt!

Comment: Added in the question. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371016/php-prepend-associative-array-with-literal-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unset($headers['PACKAGE_GUID']);
array_unshift($headers, array('PACKAGE_GUID' => 'Package GUID'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

```
$arr = array_merge(array($key => $value), $arr);
```

With `$arr` being your array, and `$key` and `$value` being the respective values of the array that you want to move to the top.

e.g.

```
$arr = array_merge(array('PACKAGE_GUID' => $arr['PACKAGE_GUID']), $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($headers['PACKAGE_GUID']);
$desired = array( 'PACKAGE_GUID' => Package GUID ) + $headers;
```

If you need an already set value you could use:

```
$value = $headers['PACKAGE_GUID'];
unset($headers['PACKAGE_GUID']);
$desired = array( 'PACKAGE_GUID' => $value ) + $headers;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can acheive this by simple assinging for your to desired array

```
$headers= Array 
(['MODULE_ID'] => 'Module ID',
['PLATFORM_ID'] => 'Platform ID',
['PACKAGE_GUID'] => 'Package GUID',
['AGGREGATE_PACKAGE'] => 'Aggregate Package',
['DELD'] => 'Deld');
```

Output as you required :

```
    $desired=
Array
(
    [PACKAGE_GUID] => $headers['PACKAGE_GUID'],
    [MODULE_ID] => $headers['MODULE_ID'],
    [PLATFORM_ID] => $headers['PLATFORM_ID'],
    [AGGREGATE_PACKAGE] =>$headers['AGGREGATE_PACKAGE'],
    [DELD] => $headers['Deld']
);
```