# How to prepend Laravel Eloquent Collection array with a key-value pair?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm fetching something from database:

```
$foo = $this->fooRepository->all()->lists('name', 'id');
```

I get:

```
Collection {#506 ▼
  #items: array:9 [▼
    "9c436867-afe9-4234-a849-253aea4f602c" => "aaa"
    "d250102b-1370-40d0-99c5-7e5bfd0a15e4" => "sss"
    "7342f212-083b-458d-8af8-24986bbb627d" => "ddd"
    "029c53ce-dc16-49fd-8d83-9d8270d9ff37" => "fff"
    "3add6a37-72e2-4054-853e-9ed8addbf3ea" => "ggg"
    "28f5a9ac-014e-4f22-bda8-e2d5b1f48273" => "hhh"
    "94fccb2c-d732-4369-9bf7-78925797e578" => "jjj"
    "5b494994-93f0-406e-b420-aceb7b6111d7" => "kkk"
    "22a7824a-c6eb-45e7-b9c5-e40c134e3ac8" => "lll"
  ]
}
```

Perfect. This collection is later passed into `Form::select` to populate select / option dropdown.

I would like to prepend this collection with another key-value pair where key will be empty string and value will contain text like "*Choose something*".

I can append:

`$foo[''] = 'Choose something…';`

so I get

```
Collection {#506 ▼
  #items: array:10 [▼
    "9c436867-afe9-4234-a849-253aea4f602c" => "aaa"
    "d250102b-1370-40d0-99c5-7e5bfd0a15e4" => "sss"
    "7342f212-083b-458d-8af8-24986bbb627d" => "ddd"
    "029c53ce-dc16-49fd-8d83-9d8270d9ff37" => "fff"
    "3add6a37-72e2-4054-853e-9ed8addbf3ea" => "ggg"
    "28f5a9ac-014e-4f22-bda8-e2d5b1f48273" => "hhh"
    "94fccb2c-d732-4369-9bf7-78925797e578" => "jjj"
    "5b494994-93f0-406e-b420-aceb7b6111d7" => "kkk"
    "22a7824a-c6eb-45e7-b9c5-e40c134e3ac8" => "lll"
    "" => "Choose something…"
  ]
}
```

but no idea **how I can move it as the first element of the collection**. I simply cannot use `array_merge` because I'm dealing with instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` rather than array so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371016/php-prepend-associative-array-with-literal-keys) won't work.

Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```php
$foo = ['' => 'Choose something…'] + $foo->all();
```

If your `$foo` must be a collection instance, simply wrap it in a collection again:

```php
$foo = collect(['' => 'Choose something…'] + $foo->all());
```

---

[I submitted a PR to laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/10811) to allow you to pass a key to `prepend`. If you're using Laravel 5.1.24 or newer, you can now do this:

```php
$foo = $this->fooRepository->all()
            ->lists('name', 'id')
            ->prepend('Choose something…', '');
```

---

Later versions of Laravel have renamed the `lists` method to `pluck`. If you're using  relatively modern version of Laravel, use `pluck` instead:

```php
$foo = $this->fooRepository->all()
            ->pluck('name', 'id')
            ->prepend('Choose something…', '');
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph. This was very helpful. Only thing I had to change was to use `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.

Comment: @slick - what do you mean? Where, what and why did you have to change?

Comment: later, inside the place that was expecting that `$foo` collection. :) All good. Don't worry!

Comment: Now it's worth mentioning that `lists` has been deprecated and `pluck` should be used instead.

Comment: `->prepend('Choose something…', '');` worked amazingly!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Try using `->prepend()`</strike>

http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_prepend

```
$foo->prepend('Choose Something')
```

---

This won't give the correct result. The index would be `0` instead of an empty string. Instead you could try something like this

```
$foo = $foo->reverse()->put('Choose Something')->reverse()
```

But using @Joseph Silber answer is probably better.

Comment: This will set the key to `0`. The OP wants the key to be an empty string.

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely correct. Could do something like `$foo->reverse()->put(‘Choose Something’)->reverse()` instead

Comment: thanks, Is there any better way like "array_unshift()" in arrays?