# Prepend key value to array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below code in a `for..loop` is there a way I can add values to the beginning of the array?

```
    $data = array();

    $initial = strtotime('11:00:00');
    for (; $initial < strtotime("23:00:59");  $initial = strtotime("+15 minutes", $initial)) {
        if ($initial > strtotime("+45 minutes", time())) {
            $row['value'] = date('Hi', $initial);
            $row['label'] = date('H:i', $initial);
            $data['data'][] = $row;
        }
    }
```

I want to add the below values to the top of the array. I have tried using `array_unshift` but I don't think it supports key-value pairs.

```
    if(!isBetween('22:00', '09:59', date('H:i'))) {
        $row['value'] = "asap";
        $row['label'] = "ASAP";
    }
```

My array output

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "value": "1145",
      "label": "11:45"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "value": "asap",
      "label": "ASAP"
    },{
      "value": "1145",
      "label": "11:45"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP prepend associative array with literal keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371016/php-prepend-associative-array-with-literal-keys)

Comment: It's not a duplicate.. Tried everything there

Comment: Can you post your array structure along with expected output

Comment: "I want to add the below values to the top of the array." - that would take place instead of `$data['data'][] = $row;`?

Comment: I have posted the array @Uchiha

Comment: `date('H:i')` - that uses the current time, not the value of $initial

Comment: My code has no problem. I just simply want to add to the top of my array @VolkerK

Comment: "have tried using array_unshift but I don't think it supports key-value pairs." - there doesn't seem to be any key/value-pair involved in the actual shift operation. The _element_ you want to unshift being an array with key/value pairs is irrelevant.

Comment: So you're saying `"value": "asap", "label": "ASAP"` is not key-value pair? @VolkerK

Comment: I say you're not unshifting key/value pairs, but an _array_ _containing_ key/value pairs. And therfore: [norepo](https://3v4l.org/Kalm0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un-shift should work if you pass the arguments correctly:

```
array_unshift($data["data"], $prepend);
```

Alternatively, you could use `array_merge`, like this:

```
$data["data"] = array_merge(array($prepend), $data["data"]);
```

With the following example data:

```
$data = [
    "data" => [
        [
            "value" => "1145",
            "label" => "11:45"
        ]
    ]
];

$prepend = [
    "value" => "asap",
    "label" => "ASAP"
];

$data["data"] = array_merge(array($prepend), $data["data"]);
print_r($data);
```

You would get this output (with both solutions):

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [value] => asap
                    [label] => ASAP
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [value] => 1145
                    [label] => 11:45
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: NB: But you could also use unshift still. For me this works:     `array_unshift($data["data"], $prepend); `

Answer (score 0):

If you need to prepend something to the array without the keys being reindexed and/or need to prepend a key value pair, you can use this short function:

```
function array_unshift_assoc(&$arr, $key, $val) { 
    $arr = array_reverse($arr, true); 
    $arr[$key] = $val; 
    return array_reverse($arr, true); 
}
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php